# Invalid conversion from char* to char

Tags: c

I'm sure there will be something more wrong with this code than this, but currently the only error I'm getting right now is the invalid conversion from char* to char.

#### Full code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define REPORTHEADING1 "     Employee              Pay      Hours     Gross     Tax       Net\n"
#define REPORTHEADING2 "     Name                  Rate     Worked    Pay       Due       Pay\n"
#define REPORTHEADING3 "     ===============       ====     ======    =====     ====      ====\n"
#define REPORTHEADING4 "                           ====     ======    =====     ====      ====\n"
#define REPORTLINEFORMAT1 "     %-20s%6.2f%11.2f%9.2f%9.2f%10.2f\n"
#define REPORTLINEFORMAT2 "     Totals              %6.2f%11.2f%9.2f%9.2f%10.2f\n"
#define REPORTLINEFORMAT3 "     Averages            %6.2f%11.2f%9.2f%9.2f%10.2f\n"

#define COUNTLINEFORMAT "     Number of employees: %-10i\n\n"

#define MAXREGHOURS 40
#define OVERTIMERATE 1.5

void PrintReportHeadings(FILE *reportFile); // printReportHeadings prototype

void InitializeAccumulators(float *totRegHour, float *totOvtHours, float *totPayrate,
        float *totGross, float *totdeferred, float *totFedtax,
        float *totStatetax, float *totSSItax, float *totNet, int *empCount); // InitializeAccumulators prototype

void InputEmployeeData(char *firstName, char *lastName,
            float *hours, float *payrate, float *deferred); // InputEmployeeData prototype

void CalculateGross(float hours, float payrate, float *regHours, float *ovtHours,
            float *gross); // CalculateGross prototype

extern void CalculateTaxes(float gross, float deferred, float * fedtax,
                float * statetax, float * ssitax); // CalculateTaxes prototype (external)

float CalculateNetPay(float gross, float fedtax, float statetax, float ssitax,
                float deferred);

void AddDetailToAccumulators(float regHours, float ovtHours, float payrate,
        float gross, float deferred, float fedtax, float statetax,
        float ssitax, float net, float *totRegHours, float *totOvtHours,
        float *totPayrate, float *totGross, float *totdeferred,
        float *totFedtax, float *totStatetax, float *totSSItax,
        float *totNet);

void PrintSummaryReport(FILE *reportFile, char fullName, float regHours, float ovtHours,
            float payrate, float gross, float deferred, float fedtax,
            float statetax, float ssitax, float net);

int main(void)
{
    float ft, st, ssit;
    char firstName[10+1];
    char lastName[15+1];
    char fullName[25+1];
    float regHours, ovtHours, hours, payrate, deferred, gross, netpay;
    float totRegHours, totOvtHours, totPayrate, totGross, totdeferred,
        totFedtax, totStatetax, totSSItax, totNet;
    int empcount;
    char answer;
    FILE * reportFile;

    reportFile = fopen("./report.txt", "wt");
    if(reportFile == NULL)
    {
        printf(" Report open request failed...\n");
        while(getchar() != '\n');
        exit(-90); // reqs <stdlib.h>
    }

    PrintReportHeadings(reportFile);

    InitializeAccumulators(&totRegHours, &totOvtHours, &totPayrate, &totGross,
        &totdeferred, &totFedtax, &totStatetax, &totSSItax, &totNet,
        &empcount); // Set all accumulators to 0

    do
    {
        InputEmployeeData(firstName, lastName, &hours, &payrate, &deferred);
        CalculateGross(hours, payrate, &regHours, &ovtHours, &gross);
        CalculateTaxes(gross, deferred, &ft, &st, &ssit);
        netpay = CalculateNetPay(gross, ft, st, ssit, deferred);
        strcpy(fullName, lastName);
        strcat(fullName, ", ");
        strcat(fullName, firstName);

        AddDetailToAccumulators(regHours, ovtHours, payrate, gross, deferred, ft, st,
            ssit, netpay, &totRegHours, &totOvtHours, &totPayrate, &totGross,
            &totdeferred, &totFedtax, &totStatetax, &totSSItax, &totNet);

        PrintSummaryReport(reportFile, fullName, regHours, ovtHours, payrate, gross, deferred, ft, st, ssit, netpay);

        empcount++;
        printf(COUNTLINEFORMAT, empcount);

        printf("  Do you have any more? (Y/N): ");
        while(getchar() != '\n')
            ;

        answer = getchar();
        printf("\n");
    }
    while(answer != 'N' && answer != 'n');

    while (getchar() != '\n')
        ;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void PrintReportHeadings(FILE *reportFile)
{
    reportFile = fopen("./report.txt", "wt");
    fprintf(reportFile, REPORTHEADING1);
    fprintf(reportFile, REPORTHEADING2);
    fprintf(reportFile, REPORTHEADING3);
}

void InitializeAccumulators(float *totRegHour, float *totOvtHours, float *totPayrate,
                float *totGross, float *totdeferred, float *totFedtax,
                float *totStatetax, float *totSSItax, float *totNet, int *empCount)
{
    totRegHour, totOvtHours, totPayrate, totGross, totdeferred,
        totFedtax, totStatetax, totSSItax, totNet, empCount = 0;
}

void InputEmployeeData(char *firstName, char *lastName, float *hours,
            float *payrate, float *deferred)
{
    printf("  Enter employee first name: ");
    scanf("%s", firstName);
    printf("  Enter employee last name: ");
    scanf("%s", lastName);
    printf("  Enter %s's hours worked: ", firstName);
    scanf("%f", hours);
    printf("  Enter %s's pay rate: ", firstName);
    scanf("%f", payrate);
    printf("  Enter %s's amount deferred: ", firstName);
    scanf("%f", deferred);
}

void CalculateGross(float hours, float payrate, float *regHours, float *ovtHours, float *gross)
{
    float overtimeHours(float hours);

    if(hours <= MAXREGHOURS)
    {
        *regHours = hours;
        *gross = hours * payrate;
    }
    else
    {
        *regHours = MAXREGHOURS;
        *ovtHours = overtimeHours(hours);
        *gross = payrate * MAXREGHOURS + OVERTIMERATE * payrate * (hours - MAXREGHOURS);
    }
}

float overtimeHours(float hours)
{
    return hours - MAXREGHOURS;
}
float CalculateNetPay(float gross, float fedtax, float statetax, float ssitax,
        float deferred)
{
    return gross - (fedtax + statetax + ssitax + deferred);
}

void AddDetailtoAccumulators(float regHours, float ovtHours, float payrate,
                float gross, float deferred, float fedtax, float statetax,
                float ssitax, float netpay, float *totRegHours, float *totOvtHours,
                float *totPayrate, float *totGross, float *totDeferred,
                float *totFedtax, float *totStatetax, float *totSSItax,
                float *totNet)
{
    *totRegHours =+ regHours;
    *totOvtHours =+ ovtHours;
    *totPayrate =+ payrate;
    *totGross =+ gross;
    *totDeferred =+ deferred;
    *totFedtax =+ fedtax;
    *totStatetax =+ statetax;
    *totSSItax =+ ssitax;
    *totNet =+ netpay;
}

void PrintSummaryReport(FILE *reportFile, char fullName, float regHours, float ovtHours,
                        float payrate, float gross, float deferred, float fedtax,
                        float statetax, float ssitax, float netpay)
{
    reportFile = fopen("./report.txt", "wt");

    fprintf(reportFile, REPORTLINEFORMAT1, fullName, payrate, regHours, gross, fedtax,
            ssitax, netpay);
    fprintf(reportFile, REPORTLINEFORMAT2, ovtHours, statetax, deferred);
}
```

Line where the error occurs:

```
PrintSummaryReport(reportFile, fullName, regHours, ovtHours, payrate, gross, deferred, ft, st, ssit, netpay);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your function signature is wrong. You probably want `char * fullname` and not `char fullname`.

```
void PrintSummaryReport(FILE *reportFile,char /* you probably want this to be a char * */ fullName,float regHours,float ovtHours,
        float payrate,float gross,float deferred,float fedtax,
        float statetax,float ssitax,float net);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this just created more errors D: I got a bunch of "undefined reference to" errors for my other functions.

Answer (score 1):

So what you're doing is asking for a pointer towards reportFile, and you're feeding it something else.

```
void PrintSummaryReport(FILE *reportFile,char fullName,float regHours,float ovtHours,
            float payrate,float gross,float deferred,float fedtax,
            float statetax,float ssitax,float net);

printSummaryReport(reportFile,fullName,regHours,ovtHours,payrate,gross,deferred,ft,st,ssit,netpay);
```

I think this would work just fine:

```
printSummaryReport(&reportFile,fullName,regHours,ovtHours,payrate,gross,deferred,ft,st,ssit,netpay);
```

Comment: This gives me the error:
cannot convert FILE to FILE* for argument to void PrintSummaryReport

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I didn't recognize the vertical scrollbar. The error you're getting is due to the fact that `fullName` inside `main` has the type of `char *`, because array labels are pointers to the very first element of the sequence of elements.

`fullName[0]` or `*(fullName + 0)` are both the same and both are a `char`, but `fullName` alone is a `char *`.

Besides, the `%s` format specifier, or the `%-20s` you use, expect a pointer to a character `char *` for substitution anyway. You are, however, attempting to give a character `char` to it. Make the following changes to resolve all the things I've stated above:

```
// prototype
void PrintSummaryReport( FILE *reportFile, char * fullName, // <-- added an asterisk *
    float regHours, float ovtHours, float payrate,          //     after char
    float gross, float deferred, float fedtax,
    float statetax, float ssitax, float net );

...

// definition
void PrintSummaryReport( FILE *reportFile, char * fullName, // <-- same here
    float regHours, float ovtHours, float payrate,
    float gross, float deferred, float fedtax,
    float statetax, float ssitax, float netpay ) { ... }
```

There are some further problems in your code. For example, your format string `"     %-20s%6.2f%11.2f%9.2f%9.2f%10.2f\n"` defined as `REPORTLINEFORMAT1` has 1 string and 5 doubles, but you are pushing 1 extra float to it with the first `fprintf` call inside the `PrintSummaryReport` function.

Then the `"     Totals              %6.2f%11.2f%9.2f%9.2f%10.2f\n"` defined as `REPORTLINEFORMAT2` will make 2nd `fprintf` expect 5 doubles, but you are pushing only 3 floats to it, 2 less than expected.

Inside the function `AddDetailtoAccumulators`, all the `= +`s are strange notation. That preceding + doesn't do anything there, probably wouldn't do anything in anywhere in C, possibly even in C++ when it's behind a float. Make sure that you didn't rather want the addition assignment `+=` operator.

There is this interesting prototype inside your `CalculateGross` function:

```
float overtimeHours( float hours );
```

It does what it should, prototypes a function that is going to get defined in some further lines, allowing you to properly use it before the definition. Since that function `overtimeHours` only gets used inside `CalculateGross` it is alright as it is, but it would still be more sensible to put it on top. You won't be able to use `overtimeHours` anywhere above its definition, outside the `CalculateGross` function.

There's something really wrong inside `InitializeAccumulators`. I think you're hoping to assign a zero to all of the variables that those pointers point to. Comma operator `,` won't help you on that. You could do a chain-assignment; but first things first, do not assign a pointer like that, rather assign the value it points to:

```
// do it like
*empCount = 0;
// not like
empCount = 0;
// which would only invalidate the pointer, make the pointer point to the memory
// location that has the address of 0, I don't think you'd want that
```

And in general, replace all those with the following:

```
*totRegHour = *totOvtHours = *totPayrate = *totGross = *totdeferred =
    *totFedtax = *totStatetax = *totSSItax = *totNet = *empCount = 0;
```

By the associativity direction of the assignment operator `=` according to this [**C Operator Precedence Table**](http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html), evaluation will happen from right to left. So, first, `0` will be assigned to `*empCount`, which would altogether evaluate to `0`. Then that `0` will be assigned to `*totNet`, and so on...

Now, in the `main` function, you apparently already open `"./report.txt"` once with the `"wt"` flag. `w` flag will truncate, i.e. clear all the contents, of an already existent file with the same name. Depending on what you want, it is alright to do that there.

However, once you do that there, you shouldn't be `fopen`ing the same file with `"wt"` flag over and over, else the contents will be cleared with each `fopen`. Since you already open it once in `main`, you should remove the following line:

```
reportFile = fopen( "./report.txt", "wt" );
```

From both the function `PrintReportHeadings` and `PrintSummaryReport`, else the file will only have the contents placed  after the last call to `fopen`.

Since you have a really scarce space for `firstName` and `lastName`, you might want to restrict the amount of characters to be read by the `scanf`s inside the `InputEmployeeData` function, like this:

```
...
scanf( "%10s", firstName );
...
scanf( "%15s", firstName );
```

This width specification thing only counts for amount of characters, doesn't take the required terminating `'\0'` into consideration. So do not write 11 and 16 there.

Also, you might want to increase the capacity of `fullName` by 2, to take the `", "` in between into account.

Answer (score 0):

The `fullname` argument in the function definition should be char `fullname[]` or `char* fullname`.